# How do I add a timeout function to my .hide function?

Tags: jquery, timeout, shopping-cart

When you hover over the the cart it will display the 2 containers below. I also set it to keep the containers displayed if you are hovering over them after they are visible.

I need a delay from when the mouse exits the cart icon to entering the containers. So the containers stay visible when you hover over them.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carticoncontainer, #userinfocontainer, #containerpoint').hover(function() { 
        setTimeout("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint", 2000); 
        if ($("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint").is(":hidden") == true) {
            $("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint").show();
        } else {
            $("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint").hide();
        }        
    });    
});
```

Comment: share your html sample also

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer like below.

When the mouse leaves the element, we can start a timer which will hide the element, but if the mouse enters back to one of these elements before the timer runs out we will cancel the timer so that the element's will not get hidden

```js
$(function() {
  var timer;
  $('#carticoncontainer, #userinfocontainer, #containerpoint').hover(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint").show();
  }, function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#userinfocontainer, #containerpoint").hide();
    }, 500)
  });
});
```

```css
#containerpoint,
#userinfocontainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carticoncontainer">carticoncontainer</div>
<div id="userinfocontainer">userinfocontainer</div>
<div id="containerpoint">containerpoint</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I wasn't sure how to apply the setTimeout to the function! You rock!